# Matching Regex groups using bash shell

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I would like to match and fetch many strings using regex groups using bash script, Linux.

I was successful if I do small matching groups with sed command. However, if I have a larger number of matching groups, it does not work properly.

This is my code:

```
   txt="toknA: ABCDEFGGDSSSE  toknB 1500        SEABCDEFGGDSSSEABCDEFGGDSSSE  1235643 CDEFGGDSSSE       toknC 64  ABCDEFGGDSSSE        ABCDEFGGDSSSE  toknD 1000  ABCDEFGGDSSSE        toknE 14306  toknF 16402238        toknG 0  toknH 0  toknI 0  toknJ 0        toknK 4930  toknL 333494 toknM fdvd swsw"

echo $txt | sed -r 's/^(toknA).*(toknB \d+).*(toknC \d+).*(toknD \d+).*(toknE \d+).*(toknF).*(toknG).*(toknH).*(toknI).*(toknJ).*(toknK).*(toknL)/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \8 \9 \10 \11 \12/'
```

This is what I have got:

```
toknA: ABCDEFGGDSSSE toknB 1500 SEABCDEFGGDSSSEABCDEFGGDSSSE 1235643 CDEFGGDSSSE toknC 64 ABCDEFGGDSSSE ABCDEFGGDSSSE toknD 1000 ABCDEFGGDSSSE toknE 14306 toknF 16402238 toknG 0 toknH 0 toknI 0 toknJ 0 toknK 4930 toknL 333494 toknM fdvd swsw
```

What I expected to get is:

```
toknA toknB 1500 toknC 64 toknD 1000 toknE 14306 toknF toknG toknH toknI toknJ toknK toknL
```

Any ideas why is that happening? can be solved in another way?

Comment: `sed` doesn't recognize the `\d` to match a digit. Use `[0-9]` instead.

Comment: I did, but it comes with another problem which is the first group appears from the 10 group onwards. Also, it does not stop with the 12 group, it fetches till the end of the text as shown below. "toknA toknB 1500 toknC 64 toknD 1000 toknE 14306 toknF toknG toknH toknI toknA0 toknA1 toknA2 333494 toknM fdvd swsw"

Comment: Backreferences are limited to \1 through \9 in `sed`. I don't know if there is a method to circumvent that.

Comment: I get rid of the limit of back references via replacing sed by perl -pe. However, it is still fetch the text up to the end and has not stopped at "toknL". Could you advise me on this how to be resolved?

Comment: echo $txt | perl -pe 's/^(toknA).*(toknB [0-9]+).*(toknC [0-9]+).*(toknD [0-9]+).*(toknE [0-9]+).*(toknF).*(toknG).*(toknH).*(toknI).*(toknJ).*(toknK).*(toknL)/$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 $10 $11 $12/'

Comment: this what i have got

Comment: toknA toknB 1500 toknC 64 toknD 1000 toknE 14306 toknF toknG toknH toknI toknJ toknK toknL 333494 toknM fdvd swsw

Comment: Just insert the `.*` between `(toknL)` and `/` in your `perl` regex.

Answer (score 1):

With just bash regex matching `[[ a =~ b ]]` -- captured pieces are stored in the `BASH_REMATCH` array

```sh
regex='(toknA)'
for x in {B..E}; do regex+=".*(tokn${x}[[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+)"; done
for x in {F..L}; do regex+=".*(tokn${x})"; done

if [[ $txt =~ $regex ]]; then
    for i in "${!BASH_REMATCH[@]}"; do
        printf "%d\t%q\n" $i "${BASH_REMATCH[i]}"
    done
    echo

    result=${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1}  # join into a single string
    echo "$result"
fi
```

outputs

```
0   toknA:\ ABCDEFGGDSSSE\ \ toknB\ 1500\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ SEABCDEFGGDSSSEABCDEFGGDSSSE\ \ 1235643\ CDEFGGDSSSE\ \ \ \ \ \ \ toknC\ 64\ \ ABCDEFGGDSSSE\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ABCDEFGGDSSSE\ \ toknD\ 1000\ \ ABCDEFGGDSSSE\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ toknE\ 14306\ \ toknF\ 16402238\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ toknG\ 0\ \ toknH\ 0\ \ toknI\ 0\ \ toknJ\ 0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ toknK\ 4930\ \ toknL
1   toknA
2   toknB\ 1500
3   toknC\ 64
4   toknD\ 1000
5   toknE\ 14306
6   toknF
7   toknG
8   toknH
9   toknI
10  toknJ
11  toknK
12  toknL

toknA toknB 1500 toknC 64 toknD 1000 toknE 14306 toknF toknG toknH toknI toknJ toknK toknL
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk '
    match($0,/^(toknA).*(toknB [0-9]+).*(toknC [0-9]+).*(toknD [0-9]+).*(toknE [0-9]+).*(toknF).*(toknG).*(toknH).*(toknI).*(toknJ).*(toknK).*(toknL)/,a) {
        for (i=1; i in a; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", (i>1? OFS : ""), a[i]
        }
        print ""
    }'
toknA toknB 1500 toknC 64 toknD 1000 toknE 14306 toknF toknG toknH toknI toknJ toknK toknL
```